# What is best rest api design when you have condition call?

Tags: javascript, rest, api

I have a condition call. To check condition you need to call other endopint. What is better api design?

e.g

```
if(fetch('api/is-data-valid')){
 const data = fetch('api/get-profile-data');
 // do something with data
}
```

or

```
const data = fetch('api/get-profile-if-data-valid');
if(data.isDataValid) {
 // do something with data
}
```

Comment: Based on the given information is hard to tell what you mean. `get-profile-data` is a strange URL anyway, because you have the HTTP request verbs `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, … so a `GET` implies to get data anyway, so `get` should not be part of the URL. And how do you relate `api/is-data-valid` and `get-profile-data` with the data you want to request? And what does it mean that the data is not valid, does it not exits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the client can't work out whether the data is valid, the API should respond accordingly, without an extra step.

Instead of checking `api/is-data-valid` to get `api/get-profile-data`, do it in one request, which hides the implementation suggested by `api/get-profile-if-data-valid`

You can only get `profile-data` if the data is valid so let the API work it out.

```
fetch('api/get-profile-data'); // returns profile data or 404
```

and let the client concentrate on displaying an error saying the data is invalid because the corresponding profile doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on a few things. In general it's best to keep the number of api calls to a minimum so doing one call instead of two is preferable. However if there are cases that someone would want to check if data is valid without getting the profile, then having the `is-data-valid` api is important.

My advice would be to have both api's but allow someone to call `get-profile-data` when it's invalid and handle that case in a well defined way. This would allow the work to be done with a single call, but still allow other use cases where checking the data validity is useful on its own.